# Do we need to trigger SXA indexes after cloning a new site?

Tags: sxa, content-search, azure-search

This is the first time working on SXA Search. We have an SXA site with search in working condition. We cloned a new site from the existing one and using master database for now but the search page is not working. Our indexing strategy currently is manual. Do we need to explicitly trigger any indexes for master also (sitecore_sxa_master_index)?

Comment: If all your indexing strategies are set to manual, it seems to me that you will indeed need to trigger index rebuilds. Also for the master database related indexes..

Answer (score 3):

If you have your indexing strategy set to `manual`, then any change you make, whether it is to an item, adding/removing an item, creating a new site, cloning a new site, anything will need an index rebuild after it is made for that change to be reflected in the index.

The question should be, why is your master index update strategy set to `manual`? Ideally, this should be set to `syncMaster` so that master changes are immediately reflected in the master indexes and the web index should be one of the publish related strategies. Otherwise, you will end up rebuilding the indexes manually very often.

Comment: Richard, master index is configured to syncMaster only whereas strategy for web is manual. But, after cloning, search in new site is not working. Any configuration we need to take care of after cloning?

Comment: well yeah - if your web is set to manual, you need to rebuild the indexes. You should set the web to `onPublishEndAsync`

Comment: But, the cloned site is pointing to master only still.